# [] vs %5B%5D in URLs

Tags: url

A question. Is there any difference that any of you know of in using %5B%5D vs [] in a URL for params?

Current: https://www.example.se?location_ids%5B%5D=123&location_ids%5B%5D=234

Vs.

Other: [https://www.example.se?location_ids[]=123&location_ids[]=234](https://www.example.se?location_ids%5B%5D=123&location_ids%5B%5D=234)

> Percent-encoding is a mechanism to encode 8-bit characters that have
> specific meaning in the context of URLs. It is sometimes called URL
> encoding. The encoding consists of substitution: A ‘%’ followed by the
> hexadecimal representation of the ASCII value of the replace
> character.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) - I have found this but it doesn’t make me understand why percent encoding is better.

Comment: The square brackets don't look like they are needed.  `location_ids=123&location_ids=234` would be a much clearer and cleaner query string. There would be no loss of information.

Comment: See also: [what is the meaning and use case of each URL encoding Reserved Characters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100765/what-is-the-meaning-and-use-case-of-each-url-encoding-reserved-characters) and [Which special characters are safe to use in url?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/498/which-special-characters-are-safe-to-use-in-url)

Comment: Stack Overflow answers this more directly: [Are square brackets permitted in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/are-square-brackets-permitted-in-urls)